# Error when I try to do mouth detection with open cv in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, face-detection, haar-classifier, opencv, python

So I am doing a simple mask detector using python and I made a code where the program first looks for a face and then checks for the mouth but when I try to load the haarcascade for mouth I get the following error

```
error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

I am making a mask detector, my code looks like this :

```
#Code for loading haar files from system directory  
face_clsfr=cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
mouth_classifier =cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_mouth.xml')

#Code for making the detection

faces=face_clsfr.detectMultiScale(gray,1.5,5) 
faces_b_w=face_clsfr.detectMultiScale(b_w,1.5,5)
```

It works perfectly fine in case of face detection but keeps throwing the error every time the mouth classifier is loaded. I tried loading a different haar file `haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml` but still no use.

**Edit** :I also tried specifying the path to the directory but throws the same error

Comment: This question is too narrow to be useful to other people using the site to learn. It does indeed look like you want people to debug your code, which is not allowed on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic **questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.**. It also seems like your question may be hard to reproduce and caused by a "typographical error". Please review your code.

Comment: @MatiasChara sorry for the inconvinience , I have narrowed down the code. This is my first time using the site.

Answer (score -1):

u can simply upload the xml file in the notebook as in anaconda 3 jupyter notebook there is a option to upload files

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).